# В каком сегменте программы находится таблица виртуальных функций класса?

Tags: c++

Имеется одиночный класс с одной виртуальной функцией, не чисто-виртуальной.

Будет ли создана таблица виртуальных функций для этого класса, если класс объявлен, но нигде в программе не создается объектов этого класса?

В каком сегменте программы располагается таблица виртуальных функций класса?

Вопросы с собеседования по С++

Comment: Хм разве создание таблицы виртуальных функции не зависит от разработчика компилятора?

Comment: Компилятор создает vtable для каждого класса(если есть класс с виртуальной функцией), для этого обьект не нужен.

Comment: Какой-то мутный вопрос. Тут нельзя сказать ничего определенного.

Answer (score 5):

Расположение vtable и vpointer зависит от реализации компилятора.
Дальше глубже в ELF будет одна структура а на win32 другая.
Для gcc можно покопаться в
`-fdump-class-hierarchy`

> "-fdump-class-hierarchy-options (C++ only)
>   Dump a representation of each class's hierarchy and virtual function table layout to a file. The file name is made by appending .class to the source file name, and the file is created in the same directory as the output file. If the `-options' form is used, options controls the details of the dump as described for the -fdump-tree options. "

взято с http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc-4.6.0/gcc/Debugging-Options.html

Answer (score 3):

> Будет ли создана таблица виртуальных функций для этого класса, если класс объявлен, но нигде в программе не создается объектов этого класса?

Это вопрос качества реализации. Может будет, а может не будет. На такие вопросы можно отвечать лишь в привязке к конкретной реализации, конкретной версии этой реализации и даже конкретных ее настроек.

С точки же зрения языка С++, никакой "таблицы виртуальных функций" не существует вообще.

Так как методы нелокального класса имеют внешнее связывание, таблица виртуальных функций скорее всего *будет* создана компилятором, т.к. в традиционной реализации на стадии компиляции компилятор не может знать, нужна эта таблица или нет. А вот на стадии сборки финального выполняемого модуля линкер уже имеет возможность выбросить ненужную таблицу виртуальных функций.

Насколько я помню, популярным подходом (GCC?) является на стадии компиляции помещать таблицу виртуальных функций в тот объектный файл, в котором располагается определение первого (в порядке объявления) не-pure виртуального метода класса.

> В каком сегменте программы располагается таблица виртуальных функций класса?

В сегменте инициализированных данных.